# Does it make a difference when I return the value from a method?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, return

This is my code currently - I'm just iterating through some lists and returning strings.

```
public string CreateCharacterName (int category) {
    string name = "";

    if(category == 0) {
        int r = Random.Range(0, Names(Roots("Characters", "CharacterNames"), 0).Count);
        name = Names(Roots("Characters", "CharacterNames"), 0)[r];
    }

    return name;
}
```

I've cut out a bunch of similar if statements, but I'm wondering if I should put the 'return name' part into each of the if statements after I've got the result, or is it fine as it is? Both work, I'm just thinking that the method will continue checking each subsequent if statement against the 'category' and THEN return the string, is that correct and is there a cost to that?

Thanks!

Comment: You are correct if the other statements are in fact plain if statements and not part of an else if. But as to cost, probably negligible unless the comparison's tend to get super complex.

Comment: They won't be more complex but there will be lots of these types of methods. And yes they aren't else/if.

Comment: Calling a `return` as early as you get the result is often referred to as "early-out", an optimization technique often employed for avoiding unnecessary calculations/operations.

Comment: Jon, if they are mutually exclusive checks, they might as well be else if so that unnecessary checking does not happen. Also, if there are more than 4 or 5, conside using a switch statement instead. Since you're only a single task in this method, there is no reason you can't return early.

Comment: If you turn your if's into else-if's then it'd be the same as adding return in each if. However, adding the return line in each statement also makes it more difficult to read

Comment: Thanks for the info guys, I will probably be changing to a switch for my larger methods.

Comment: Adding multiple return to this kind of code also make it harder to debug. You might forget to add a breakpoint on a return somewhere.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's fine as it is. Your [cyclomatic complexity](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms182212.aspx) is 2, i.e there is only 1 binary path through your code, which is good. Moving the `return name;` statement would increase it a little, which isn't bad though. As a rule of thumb, try to reduce complexity.

Comment: Cool, I'll have to keep that info in mind for the future - I tend to overcomplicate!

Answer (score 0):

if microsecond optimisation is important why not skip using the variable and just use:

`return Names(Roots("Characters", "CharacterNames"), 0)[r];`

Comment: Thanks for the tip - it's not particularly for that I just was worried that eventually it'd get a bit much, but you're right I probably don't need the variable.